# Delphi 7: How to copy non-latin text to clipboard? (convert to Unicode?)

Tags: delphi, winapi, unicode, delphi-7

I have code like this to copy some text to clipboard.

```
uses Clipbrd;

var
  text: string;
begin
  text := 'Some non-latin text, for example Russian: Привет!'

  Clipboard.AsText := text;
end;
```

Win7-8 OS, Russian locale (and format) set in OS Region settings, Delphi 7.

The problem is that it works only when I switch (shift+alt) to Russian **keyboard layout** when copying. Otherwise it will be pasted as `"Ïðèâåò!"` instead of `"Привет!"`.

How can I fix that?

I think that I need somehow convert text to Unicode and call Unicode clipboard copy function from WinAPI? But how to do that?

Comment: @MatheusFreitas I know. But I think it is possible to convert string to Unicode and call some winapi function?

Comment: You could use StringToWideChar.

Comment: See WinAPI function MultiByteToWideChar.

Comment: @KonstantinL StringtoWideChar internally calls the function you'd suggested

Comment: @Alex11223 I would suggest to use only unicode strings in your programs. Not only when copying to clipboard.

Comment: @KonstantinL in Delphi7? Looks like too complicated. At least I will need to replace all standard controls to some custom controls that support unicode.

Comment: @Alex Those are the TNT Unicode controls. It's actually quite feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the text to Unicode by whatever means you see fit. In Delphi 7 that typically involves using `WideString`.

Once you have the text encoded as UTF-16, for instance in a `WideString`, you need to call `SetClipboardData` using the `CF_UNICODETEXT` clipboard format. This is wrapped by Delphi as the `SetAsHandle` method of the global `Clipboard` object.

I've not tested it, but this function should set you on the way:

```
uses
  Windows, Clipbrd;

procedure SetClipboardText(const Text: WideString);
var
  Count: Integer;
  Handle: HGLOBAL;
  Ptr: Pointer;
begin
  Count := (Length(Text)+1)*SizeOf(WideChar);
  Handle := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, Count);
  Try
    Win32Check(Handle<>0);
    Ptr := GlobalLock(Handle);
    Win32Check(Assigned(Ptr));
    Move(PWideChar(Text)^, Ptr^, Count);
    GlobalUnlock(Handle);
    Clipboard.SetAsHandle(CF_UNICODETEXT, Handle);
  Except
    GlobalFree(Handle);
    raise;
  End;
end;
```

Comment: Or use protected hack for directly calling `SetBuffer` of Clipboard.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz My code is better because it checks for errors!

Comment: I'm with @Sertac here. Check out the flow `TClipboard.SetBuffer`. It will never fail silently.

Comment: @FreeConsulting If `GlobalAlloc` or `GlobalLock` fail then you will end up with an AV, invalid write to `$00000000`, in the `Move` because `DataPtr` will be `nil`. So yes, it will not silently fail. That's not such a bad way to go. Protected hack is also not unreasonable. I personally don't find the code in my answer to be difficult to write or understand.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why **try/except/raise** instead of simply **try/finally**?

Comment: @craig because you must only call GlobalFree if you were not able to pass ownership to the clipboard

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then it's cool. It is somewhat unfortunate that nothing in the naming convention indicates transfer of ownership though. And even more unfortunate is that (at least in D2007) `SetAsHandle` does not check for errors in its call to `SetClipboardData`. So in theory, the method could fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, by thees means you can also convert Encoding in the clipboard if you catch WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message - very usefull with old versions of delphi, e.g. for Russian Language.
Here is a full working code:

(N.B. This buffer listening tecnique will only work for Windows Vista and newer OS, that's why I use dynamic WinAPI linking, see this article -
 http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=9)

```
type
  TAddOrRemoveClipboardFormatListener = function (hWndNewViewer : HWND) : BOOL; stdcall;

var _isClipboardChangeRequired : boolean;
var _addClipboardFormatListener, _removeClipboardFormatListener : TAddOrRemoveClipboardFormatListener;

procedure TDM.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
<...>
  _addClipboardFormatListener := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('user32.dll'), 'AddClipboardFormatListener');
  _removeClipboardFormatListener := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('user32.dll'), 'RemoveClipboardFormatListener');

  if (Assigned(_addClipboardFormatListener) AND NOT _addClipboardFormatListener(Application.Handle)) then
    begin
      _isClipboardChangeRequired := false;
      ShowMessage('Не удалось установить перехватчик изменения буфера обмена! Кодировка при вставке в контролы может быть неверной!' +
        sLineBreak + 'Код ошибки (' + IntToStr(GetLastError()) + '): ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
    //      WriteLog([ssWarn], ClassName, 'Не удалось установить перехватчик изменения буфера обмена! Кодировка при вставке в контролы может быть неверной!' +
    //      sLineBreak + 'Код ошибки (' + IntToStr(GetLastError()) + '): ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
    end
    else
        _isClipboardChangeRequired := true;
<...>
end;

procedure TDM.DataModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if Assigned(_removeClipboardFormatListener) then
    _removeClipboardFormatListener(Application.Handle);
end;

procedure TDM.ApplicationEvents_ClipboardChangeMessage(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
const
    // WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE is not defined in the Messages unit of all supported
  // versions of Delphi, so we defined it here for safety.
  // (взято отсюда: http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=9)
  WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = $031D;
  MAX_CLIPBOARD_OPEN_ATTEMPTS = 3;
var
    textBuf : array[0..512] of WideChar;
  clipHandle : THandle;
  dataPtr: Pointer;
  dataSize : integer;
  str : string;
  attemptCount : integer;
  isClipboardOpened : boolean;
begin
  // если система не поддерживает слежение за буфером обмена, прекращаем дальнейшие попытки это сделать
    if (NOT Assigned(_addClipboardFormatListener)) then
    begin
        ApplicationEvents_ClipboardChange.OnMessage := nil;
      Exit;
    end;
  if (Msg.message = WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE) AND (Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_UNICODETEXT)) then
    if NOT _isClipboardChangeRequired then
        begin
            _isClipboardChangeRequired := true;
        Exit;
      end
    else
      begin
        attemptCount := 1;
        isClipboardOpened := false;
        repeat
          try
            Clipboard.Open();
            isClipboardOpened := true;
          except
            if (attemptCount >= MAX_CLIPBOARD_OPEN_ATTEMPTS) then
              begin
                OutputDebugString(PChar('Внимание: Нет доступа к буферу обмена - невозможно изменить его кодировку!'));
                Exit;
              end
            else
              inc(attemptCount);
          end;
        until isClipboardOpened;
        clipHandle := Clipboard.GetAsHandle(CF_UNICODETEXT);
        dataPtr := GlobalLock(clipHandle);
        if (dataPtr <> nil) then
          try
            dataSize := GlobalSize(clipHandle);
            ZeroMemory(@textBuf, sizeof(textBuf));
            CopyMemory(@textBuf, dataPtr, dataSize);
            SetString(str, textBuf, dataSize);
            str := Trim(str);
            Clipboard.AsText := str;
            _isClipboardChangeRequired := false;
            OutputDebugString(PChar('Clipboard encoding converted!'));
          finally
            GlobalUnlock(clipHandle);
          end;
        Clipboard.Close();
      end;
end;
```